# SharePoint services WSDL specification

Tags: web-services, sharepoint, wsdl

What is the reason why hitting, for example, http:///_vti_bin/UserGroup.asmx?wsdl gives me a not full wsdl specification (if compared with http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd965659%28v=office.12%29.aspx)?

What I mean about not full: it does not contain some of complex types definition, e.g. User (unlike the full one), so this types are no generated by the wsdl.exe.

I have a question in regard of this: is it safe to generate c# web service stub basing on specification from MSDN or this approach is dangerous due to possible changes in contract?

Answer (score 0):

For your first question as to the WSDL not being the same: it really should be equivalent and contain all the types! Whenever you append /_vti_bin/UserGroup.asmx?wsdl to your site's URL, SharePoint should definitely display the FULL WSDL, including the complex type definitions, etc. I just tried it now against my own SharePoint instance and the WSDL returned from http:// mysite.com/ ...snip... /pierre/_vti_bin/UserGroup.asmx?wsdl is pretty much the same size as the one from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd965659%28v=office.12%29.aspx and a quick check to make sure complex types are in both places confirm that.

To answer your second question: I think you should NOT create your Web Service stubs and skeletons based on the WSDL in the documentation. Instead use the WSDL returned from your site. If you're not getting all the complex types in the WSDL returned from SharePoint, you should fix that issue first.

First thing I would try: download SOAPui (free) and simply plugin the URL that ends with ?wsdl and create sample requests. Maybe you'll run into access issues (UAG or other) but at least you'll know that the WSDL is well formed. If SOAPui can generate the client code based on the WSDL, you can too (using wsdl2java or the wsdl2dotnet equivalent; I can't remember the name of the .net version).

And yes, it's dangerous to copy the WSDL from the docs but I'd be more worried about some things being abbreviated or documentation going stale, etc.

As for the contract changing, I'm using the UserGroup.asmx?wsdl endpoint since 2009 and it still works on newer versions of SharePoint (even after the upgrade to SP2010). And I'm using java as the client code. Microsoft really nailed the Web Services in SharePoint, it was surprisingly easy to integrate our java stack and make calls to/from the SharePoint web services. And it was also very inter-operable with the other tools we use to test Web Services like SOAPui, etc.